# controlling indentation with biblatex alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex, indentation, biber

I have the following minimal code using biblatex:

test.tex

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\raggedright
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib

```
@article{thorvarson61,
   author={Þorvarson, Æsir},
   title={Using \LaTeX{} in Norse Linguistics},
   journal={J Nor Ling},
   volume={1},
   year=1981,
   pages={1--10}
}
```

Biber is required as I have author names with non-ASCII UTF-8 characters in my bibliography. However, what I get is indented as follows:

[image: undesired indentation]

While I want Indentation to look like:

[image: desired indentation]

The latter is from a file which includes the following piece of code and a manually created bibliography list (the code does not appear to affect bibtex or biblatex generated bibliographies)

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
       \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5\parsep}
       \wscgraggedright
       \setlength{\parsep}{1.0ex}
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
```

I tried copying the `\defbibenvironment` from `alphabetic.bst` and modifying it, but was not able to achieve a similar style, as all changes to `\leftmargin` appear to affect the label as well in an undesirable fashion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would it be possible to turn the code snippets into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that we can just copy and run in our machines to investigate the issue? It helps those trying to help you save time and makes sure that the proposed solution works with your document set up.

Comment: @moewe I turned the 4 lines of code into a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of

```
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}% <-- adjust this to your liking, the standard is 2\labelsep
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

Comment: This appears to work with the minimal example. I'll have to try it with the full code tomorrow. What would be the closest equivalent to the template code I gave? (Replacing `\wcsgraggedright` with `\raggedright` as they are approximately equivalent)

Comment: @Joe There are several ways to get a ragged bibliography including the `block=ragged` option, or the more radical `\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}`.

Comment: For `\raggedright`, just prepending it before `\printbibliography` seems to work fine. I meant getting the spacings to match as well as possible

Comment: @Joe I can suggest `\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{-0.5\parsep}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{1.0ex}` but I guess that the standard set-up of BibTeX lists differs a bit from `biblatex`'s so just copying the numbers might not help, you will have to experiment a bit.